# What is the best practices for Apache Kafka Producer Configuration?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Currently I am using kafka-0.8.0, and using zk.connect property for broker discovery which is not mentioned in the documentation for 0.8.0 version but is in 0.7.0. 
broker.list is introduced in 0.8.0.

So, my questions is which is the best practice to connect? Why?

For reference:
http://kafka.apache.org/07/configuration.html
https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html